# May I say "The client sent me a letter >asking< to [do something]"?

Tags: participle-clauses

Can I say:

> The client sent me a letter **asking** if we could change the information for them.

or should it be:

> The client sent me a letter **and asked** if we could change the information for him.

I'm confused with the first one, why past tense can be used with `verb`+*ing*?

Comment: The grammar of your title question (_Is it this grammar correct?_ is already not correct. How should we explain the grammar to you?

Answer (score 3):

> The client sent me a letter **asking** if we could change the information for them.

This sentence is OK grammatically. But mind that in most contexts it would mean:

> The client sent me a letter. The letter **contained** his request to change some information for the client.

The second sentence is also grammatical:

> The client sent me a letter **and** asked if we could change the information for him.

But note the difference in meaning:

> The client sent me a letter. He also asked (by phone, or personally, or in other way, but **not in the letter**) if we could change some information for him.

To make the second sentence identical in meaning to the first, use the relative pronoun **that**:

> The client sent me a letter **that** asked if we could change the information for him.

If you want to investigate the grammar behind all this, read up on "relative clauses" (they use relative pronouns like **that**) and "participial clauses" (they use verbs ending in **-ing** and **-ed**).

You ask:

> I'm confused with the first one, why past tense can be used with **verb+ing**?

Because the **verb+ing** (present participle) really connects not to the verb **sent** but to the noun **letter**:

> - What kind of letter? - Letter **asking** if we could change some information.

Comment: What's the subject of the verb *asking*?

Comment: *Letter*, I guess. I could be wrong. Correct me if I'm wrong, @Araucaria.

Comment: +1, nice post. :) -- Don't worry, CopperKettle, the member @Araucaria is soon gonna be putting up some answer posts, and he'll get his comeuppance then. Be sure to collect a basket or two full of tomatoes, for that day is coming very soon. :D

Comment: @F.E.: Getting corrections is the best way to learn a grammar! (0: Is the definite article necessary before "member Araucaria"?

Comment: Usually, for that "member" has already come up in this discussion, and so, we use "the" to refer to old info. Also, "the" would be used anyway because we're talking about a specific person: "the member (known as) Araucaria". :)